# Timer in Every Row of Table

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I would like to add a running time/ stopwatch for every row showing the time spent in each process. The timer just shows at the first row and nothing on the rest.

The date to be used would come from a database.

Here's a snippet of my code for reference:

```
<?php
  
  echo "<h2>On-Going Repairs</h2>";

  $query = "SELECT tca_ro, tca_csplate, tca_name, tca_start, tca_process FROM tcs.tca_bp_process WHERE date(tca_start) = curdate() AND tca_status = 'Started'";

  if($query_result = mysqli_query($link,$query)){

    if(mysqli_num_rows($query_result) > 0)
    {
        echo "<div class='card-body'>";
            echo "<div class='table-responsive'>";
                echo "<table class='table table-bordered' id='dataTable' width='100%' cellspacing='0'>";
                    echo "<thead>";
                        echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<th>RO NUMBER</th>";
                            echo "<th>CS NUMBER</th>";
                            echo "<th>TECHNICIAN</th>";
                            echo "<th>START</th>";
                            echo "<th>PROCESS</th>";
                            echo "<th>DURATION</th>";
                        echo "</tr>";
                    echo "</thead>";

                    echo "<tbody>";

                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_result))
                    {
                        echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td>".$row['tca_ro']."</td>"; 
                            echo "<td>".$row['tca_csplate']."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$row['tca_name']."</td>";
                            echo "<td><input type='text' id='date' value='".$row['tca_start']."'</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$row['tca_process']."</td>";
                            echo"<td><div id='data'></div></td>";
                        echo "</tr>";
                    }                                    
                    echo "</tbody>";
                echo "</table>";
              echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
    } 
  }
?

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function func(){

      var dateValue = document.getElementById("date").value;
      var date = Math.abs(new Date(dateValue).getTime() / 1000).toFixed(0);
      var currentDate = Math.abs((new Date().getTime() / 1000).toFixed(0));
      var diff = currentDate - date;

      var hours = Math.floor(diff/3600) % 24;
      var minutes = Math.floor(diff/60) % 60;
      var seconds = diff % 60;

      var time_str = hours + " : " + minutes +" : "+ seconds

      document.getElementById("data").innerHTML =hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds;
    }

    func();
    setInterval(func, 1000);
  </script>
```

Hope you can help me out. Thank you in advance

Comment: You cant have multiple ids with the same value in your DOM. And what are you trying to measure?

Answer (score 0):

You have no need for Timer as they are in the Java programming language. All you need to do is display the values from a database.

Assuming you have start and end times in  tca_start and tca_end, and duration in  tca_duration just add lines as

```
echo "<td>".$row['tca_start']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['tca_end']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['tca_duration']."</td>";
```

If that is not what you are looking for, maybe enhance you question.